# How the asp.net server controls implemented

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-controls

Just want to have a rough idea how complicated server controls(those built-in controls, such as calendar, treeview) were implemented in ASP.net. I was thinking they are implemented by javascript. But if that's the case, how it works when javascript is switched off on web browser. Thanks.

Comment: Depends on which web controls you are referring to.

Comment: Let's say, a calendar.

Comment: So do you need to know how a calendar control works or some other control?

Comment: Then let's just talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

I did some test and the results are some server controls rely on javascript, such as the calendar. They will not work if I switched off javascript in web browser. Some simple ones are ok, such as the textbox. I am a little bit surprised about the result for the asp.net has no backup solution for js disabled.